# Azure Role to delete ARM Virtual Disks

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I am in a group which has been given roles of Virtual Machine Contributor, Storage Account Contributor and etc.

May we ask what specific role does the group has to have in order to delete these unattached disks from our azure subscription account.

> Failed to delete disk
>   'CSAZAPFSENSE01_OsDisk_1'. Error: The
>   client 'bryan.bercero@domain.my' with object id
>   '0e549171-14a2-4dc6-b0f8' does not have authorization to
>   perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/disks/delete' over scope
>   'CSAZAPFSENSE01_OsDisk_1' or the
>   scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your
>   credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any built in role that provides the specific permission **Microsoft.Compute/disks/delete**. It comes as a part of [Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) role that the group has.

You can look at what permissions each built-in role provides you here - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles.

In addition you can [create custom roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) that will provide the specific permissions.